# How can i make python shuffleCards program output one of each card and not random amounts

Tags: python, math, random, shuffle

Python newbie
How can i make the output be 52 cards but one of each and not randomly created cards. As of now output becomes for example 2 clover, 2 clover, 5 diamonds .. etc.
I know its an issue with the shuffeling i am doing but i am not allowed to use "random.shuffle"

```
import math
import random

def main():
    createDeck()
    shuffleDeck()
    printDeck()

deck = ['A'] * 52


def createDeck():
    suits = [" Heart", " Spades", " Clover", " Diamonds"]
    cardsHeld = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]

    for i in range(len(deck)):
        deck[i] = cardsHeld[int(i%13)] + suits[int(i/13)] 
        


def shuffleDeck():
    rand=0
    num = 0

    for i in range(len(deck)):
        rand = random.random()
       
        num = rand * 52
        num = math.floor(num)
        deck[i] = deck[num] 
          

def printDeck():    
    for i in range(len(deck)):    
        print(deck[i])   
main()
```

I changed

```
def shuffleDeck():
    rand=0
    num = 0

    for i in range(len(deck)):
        rand = random.random()
       
        num = rand * 52
        num = math.floor(num)
        deck[i] = deck[num]
```

with

```
def shuffleDeck():
   random.shuffle(deck)
```

That worked however i am not allowed to use "random.shuffle(deck)" So im not sure how i should be doing the shuffeling then.

Comment: In "createDeck" swap the cards instead of copying the card from random place.

Comment: Just replace `deck[i] = deck[num]` with `deck[i], deck[num] = deck[num], deck[i]`.

Comment: And with `itertools` the deck could be constructed with `deck = [f'{value} {suit}' for value, suit in itertools.product(cardsHeld, suits)]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `deck[i] = deck[num]` you overwrite the value at index `i` while keeping the same value at index `num`. You need to swap the values with `deck[i], deck[num] = deck[num], deck[i]`. But there's no need to write something like this yourself. Simply use one line of code with [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) from Pythons standard library.

if you do `import random` the code is:

```
def shuffle_deck(deck):
    random.shuffle(deck)
```

I changed the name of the function to be consistent with the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) and added `deck` as a parameter.